# Solve atom error message

Tags: python, anaconda, atom-editor

I received an error on atom, it asked to install ipkernal using pip.

Not sure what to do. I have Anaconda on my system and not pip. Can someone explains whats the error about and how can I solve it in using anaconda. 
I was running a python code and saved the file as `.py`.

```
import pandas as pd

wd = pd.read_csv("winequality-red", sep = ";")

five = wd.head()
print ("five")
```

Error message:

```
No kernel for grammar Python found <br>
Check that the language for this file is set in Atom and that you have a Jupyter kernel installed for it.<br>
To detect your current Python install you will need to run:<br>
python -m pip install ipykernel<br>
python -m ipykernel install --user
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer, but you might have better luck on the dedicated [Atom forums](https://discuss.atom.io/).

In your case though, it looks like you haven't installed the proper kernels `Hydrogen` needs to run Python with. (Of course, I'm just assuming you're using Hydrogen. You haven't actually provided any details about *how* you are trying to run it).

From the Hydrogen documentation, it takes you to this page for Python kernels.
https://nteract.io/kernels/python

In particular, I think you want to run the command `conda install ipykernel`